# Set tinymce direction to rtl

Tags: tinymce

I install Tinymce editor to my site. And now i need to set the default direction to `RTL` not `LTR`.

I try this way but not work with me :-

```
#tinymce p {
 direction : rtl;
}
```

How can do that ??

Comment: In WordPress, if you enable a RTL language, [TinyMCE directionaly setting](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:directionality) is atuomatically set to RTL. What are trying to do exactly?

Comment: where can set this setting

Comment: "I install Tinymce editor to my site" - are you actually using WordPress?

Comment: yes i use WordPress

Comment: 3 years later, RTL editing still a PITA. I thought Wordpress was a good choice. I thought a decade-old global platform would have ironed out such issues. I thought wrong.

Answer (score 6):

In wordpress, the editor will support and will be in RTL by default if you install it in an rtl language, for example, if you install wordpress with the hebrew UI the editor will be rtl by default.

The problem is if you install the hebrew UI but change your profile to use the English one, in order to still use the editor in rtl mode while using the English UI you can add this code to functions.php or a site plugin:

```
function Eyal_setEditorToRTL($settings)
{
    $settings['directionality'] = 'rtl';
    return $settings;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'Eyal_setEditorToRTL');
```

The filter alters the default settings for the tinyMCE editor and set it in rtl mode.

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank You!

Comment: This is the exact wordpress friendly mechanism to change default 'directionality' for tinyMCE Editor. But it not worked for my website having 'Neve' template but worked in my two other sites having 'Flatsome' template.

Answer (score 2):

```
 tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#editor', 
        directionality :"rtl"
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why your code helps

Comment: Might be of interest: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/directionality/